# After performing an action on a child controller in Rails, how can I control where a visitor is redirected to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I'm modeling some conversations in my Rails project: I have Topics as a parent model, and Comments as a child of that model.

When a user visits the `http://www.example.com/topics/show/2` page, my project shows them many comments related to the given topic. On that page, if a user clicks the delete button on a comment record, a request is sent to `comments_controller` and executes the `destroy` action. The request then redirects the user to the root page.

Instead of this behavior, I want them to be redirected back to the topic page with the comments. How can I get this behavior? I'm confused about this because only the ID of the comment being deleted is passed to `comments_controller` from the topic view page. It doesn't pass the ID of the topic that the comment was attached to, so I can't use that to direct the user back to the `/topics/show/2` page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of your action:

```
redirect_to :back
```